# Have been trying to solve the n-queens problem using stack/backtracking with Java. Not very experienced, trying to see where I went wrong

Tags: java, loops, stack

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
        while(filled <= 7) {

            conflictTest(conflict);

            if (conflict == false) {
                xPosition.push(x);
                filled++;
                y++;
                n++;
                x = 0;
            }
            else if (x == n){
                x = xPosition.pop() + 1;
                n--;
                y--;
                filled--;
            }
            else if (conflict = true) {
                x++;                
            }
            conflict = false;
        }

        printSolution();
    }
```

My output has been a stack filled with zeros for the x value and I do not understand why. It seems in the first if statement, whatever I change the x value too after I push the first value to the stack, I receive that in the rest of the stack. I would think resetting it to zero as it is in the code would be the right way as when it loops back it would see a conflict.

It seems to do this regardless of the conflict test I have in a seperate method so I didn't see it necessary to post here, as well as my print out method being correct.

also the while statement in the beginning is limited at 8 at the moment just so I can try and get it to work in general first

**Update**

Stackoverflow was telling me I had too much code soI didn't add conflict method. Here it is

```
public static void conflictTest(boolean conflict) {

        for (int i = 1; i < xPosition.size(); i++) { 
            int j = xPosition.size()-i;
            if (x == xPosition.get(i) || x == xPosition.get(i) + j 
                    || x == xPosition.get(i) - j) { 
                conflict = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I cannot see the code that will update conflict to true, is conflict a global variable ?

Comment: @MohdAlomar I added an edit to the original post sorry

Answer (score 0):

From your code conflict will never be true; because boolean data type are passed by value. See example below :

```
   public class Test{
     public static void makeMeTrue(boolean youThinkIamTrue)
     {
         //local value set to true but your original youThinkIamTrue still false 
         youThinkIamTrue = true;
     }
     public static void main(String []args){
        boolean youThinkIamTrue = false;
        makeMeTrue(youThinkIamTrue);
        //will print false
        System.out.println(youThinkIamTrue);

     }
}
```

to solve the issue you should change your function

```
public static boolean conflictTest(boolean conflict) {

    for (int i = 1; i < xPosition.size(); i++) { 

        int j = xPosition.size()-i;

        if (x == xPosition.get(i) || x == xPosition.get(i) + j 
                || x == xPosition.get(i) - j) { 

            return true;
        }
    }
    return conflict;
}
```

and update your calling code to

```
conflict = conflictTest(conflict);
```